# Microsoft Office 1707 - MSCOMCTL.OCX - You do not have an appropriate license to use this functionality

Tags: vb6, office365

I have encountered a strange issue with Microsoft Office 365 Business. I have a trio of VB6 COM Add-ins which were functioning correctly until I upgraded from build 1701 to build 1707. Now every time one of my add-ins displays a dialog, I now receive runtime error 429 with the message "You do not have an appropriate license to use this functionality".

I have done a bit of debugging and the issue appears to be with the use of MSCOMCTL.OCX.

Strangely, I do not receive the same error when using the OCX within a user form in VBA or within a compiled EXE on the same machine.

I have checked the registry and there appears to be a valid license entry for the OCX under HKCR\Licences. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

I am running Windows 10 Pro and Microsoft Office 365 Business Version 1707 (Build 8326.2062 Click-to-Run).

Comment: I doubt Office 365 includes design-time licenses for the VB6 OCXs.  However you seem to be talking about a run-time use within a DLL compiled with VB6.  In that case you are probably creating control instances dynamically and failed to include the necessary license information within your DLL.  Look up `Licenses Collection` in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but none of the controls are dynamically created and as such I get "The control 'MSComctlLib.ListViewCtrl.2' cannot be added to the Licenses collection, because it is already referenced by the project."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a bug.

I think that it will solve by replacing MSCOMCTL.OCX.

http://support.inera.com/support/solutions/articles/11000036093-july-august-2017-update-for-office-2016-version-1707-causes-paragraph-styling-dialog-to-disappear

---

On **32bit** versions of Windows:

1. Copy the file [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\SystemX86\mscomctl.ocx] to a safe location
2. Copy the file [C:\Windows\System32\mscomctl.ocx] to [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\SystemX86], overwriting the newer copy of this file with the older file

---

On **64bit** versions of Windows:

1. Copy the file [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\SystemX86\mscomctl.ocx] to a safe location
2. Copy the file [C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscomctl.ocx] to [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\SystemX86], overwriting the newer copy of this file with the older file

Comment: Please add more details in your answer; external links should be used only as a supplemental reference, as they may break

Comment: I can confirm that replacing mscomctl32.ocx with an older version does prevent the issue.

I was also able to recompile my add-ins using the newer ocx on my Windows 7 build environment. This also prevents the issue, but I had to design against the old version, close the IDE, replace the OCX and then do a command line build to avoid getting similar errors appearing in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I solved it when I updated it to 16.0.8326.2087.